# ASP.NET: writing AuthenticationProvider for a custom OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication

I've made a custom Authentication Server which implements OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider and all the other classes which are necessary to make authentication with this server possible. This server consists of an ASP.NET Web API project. This is a stand-alone project and I want to use it to authentication certain applications with it by using OAuth 2.0. Think about multiple ASP.NET MVC 5 websites. The AuthenticationServer and the websites are hosted apart from eachother.

That's why I want to create a custom AuthenticationProvider which I can use in my ASP.NET MVC 5 websites to authenticate a user. 
This [Overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rP40W.jpg) is a global picture of what I want to achieve.

I want each client/website to have a login screen where they can fill their user credentials in, then I want the website to do a OAuth handshake with the configured ClientId & ClientSecret and the given user credentials. Then, if the user is authenticated, the user should be able to save it's access token and all the other user-information (like name, etc.) in a cookie or a session.

I tried to develop an AuthenticationProvider for it, so it would be easy to port the authentication to multiple ASP.NET websites, but I was not able to succeed yet. I also don't know if my approach by using a AuthenticationProvider for this is the right thing to do, so suggestions about this and alternative approaches are very welcome.

I already tried developing such an AuthenticationProvider and tried configuring it in the Startup-class:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    // For more information on configuring authentication, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType("ExternalCookie");
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "ExternalCookie",
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive,
            CookieName = ".AspNet.ExternalCookie",
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
        });
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        var options = new CustomAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = "42ff5dad3c274c97a3a7c3d44b67bb42",
            ClientSecret = "jh52g35vnm23bjh54g235jhg234",
            Provider = new CustomAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnAuthenticated = context =>
                {
                    context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("urn:token:customprovider", context.AccessToken));

                    return Task.FromResult(true);
                }
            }
        };
        app.UseCustomAuthentication(options);
    }
}
```

However, the provider is able to communicate with the AuthenticationServer, but it's not able to authenticate the client. I don't know how this is caused. It seems like the AuthenticationProvider is not sending the ClientId & Secret (correctly) in the request.

I created a little prototype to test my AuthenticationServer which used a OAuth2Client from Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Client to authenticate a user:

```
string tokenEndpoint = "http://localhost:61182/oauth/token"; // Token end point
OAuth2Client client = new OAuth2Client(new Uri(tokenEndpoint), "42ff5dad3c274c97a3a7c3d44b67bb42", "jh52g35vnm23bjh54g235jhg234"); // Client ID and Secret
TokenResponse tokenResponse = client.RequestResourceOwnerPasswordAsync("testAcc", "test").Result;
```

The AuthenticationServer was able to handle this and return an Accesstoken when authentication was successful. Then the Accesstoken is used to do authenticated requests to the controllers within the AuthenticationServer.
This was successful, but I want to implement this for an ASP.NET MVC website.

My question is: What is the best approach to implement custom authentication with my AuthenticationServer for ASP.NET MVC websites?